# Make this as a dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem of making a dimensional array, please help me im using php, this is my scenario

```
$arrayname = array["john","mell","ben","henz","len"];
$arrayage = array["10","15","58","12","13"];
$arraygender = array["male","female","male","male","female"];
```

I want to make it like

```
$arrayidentify = array['name' => 'john', 'age' => '10', 'gender' => 'male'];
```

And so on,

Please help thanks a lot

Comment: `'name' => 'male'` - I am pretty sure you meant to use "gender" and not "name".

Comment: Hi Rumel and welcome to SO.  You have likely recieved negative votes here, because your code above is invalid.  Please check array syntax according to the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php .  Also not providing any attempts at a solution will be frowned upon.  You can edit your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     class Person { 
        public $name = "pname";
        public $age = "21";
        public $gender = "MaleOrFemale";

        function __construct($name,$age,$gender){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }
}
```

you can use OOP methods and create an object to store the data of a person and create an array of persons

example

```
$steve = new Person("Steve Jobs","60","Male");
```

this'll create a person object $steve with name steve , age 60 , gender Male

you can create may person objects as you wish and put it on an array

```
$jeff = new Person("Jeff Bezos","50","Male");
$bill = new Person("Bill Gates","64","Male");
```

put all the above in an array as shown below

```
$persons = array($steve,$jeff,$bill);
```

try the below code self study and understand it i have used objects and constructor functions learn about them in w3schools.com

```
<?php 


class Person { 
    public $name = "pname";
    public $age = "21";
    public $gender = "MaleOrFemale";

    function __construct($name,$age,$gender){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->age = $age;
    $this->gender = $gender;
}
}
$steve = new Person("Steve Jobs","60","Male");
$jeff = new Person("Jeff Bezos","50","Male");
$bill = new Person("Bill Gates","64","Male");

$persons = array($steve,$jeff,$bill);

foreach($persons as $person){
    echo"Person Name : ".$person->name."<br>";
    echo"Person Age : ".$person->age."<br>";
    echo"Person Gender : ".$person->gender."<br><br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: While this is an interesting post, the OP is trying to wrangle the contents of a few arrays into another.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the array_map solution provided by @ajay-kumar is the best, 
I will propose a solution more dynamic and easer to read

```
function bindDatas(&$resultSolution, $inputData, $keyName) 
{
    foreach ($inputData as $key => $value) {
        $resultSolution[$key][$keyName] = $value;
    }
}
```

the test code some think like this:

```
//your code here
bindDatas($resultSolution, $arrayname, 'name');
bindDatas($resultSolution, $arrayage, 'age');
bindDatas($resultSolution, $arraygender, 'gender');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultSolution);
echo '</pre>';
```

it's true thar $key variable refer to position in the $inputData, but we an use it here because we want to keep the order in the global array

Comment: An array_map or simple loop would be easier to read.  How is this more dynamic?

Comment: @Progrock I agree with you, array_map is much easier, but the dynamic word used here, mean that you can add other items [like departure name or country name]

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop will do here:

```
<?php
$names   = ["john","mell","ben","henz","len"];
$ages    = ["10","15","58","12","13"];
$genders = ["male","female","male","male","female"]; 

for($i=0, $c=count($names), $out=[]; $i<$c; $i++) {
    $out[] = [
        'name'   => $names[$i],
        'age'    => $ages[$i],
        'gender' => $genders[$i]
    ];
}

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'john',
      'age' => '10',
      'gender' => 'male',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'mell',
      'age' => '15',
      'gender' => 'female',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'ben',
      'age' => '58',
      'gender' => 'male',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'henz',
      'age' => '12',
      'gender' => 'male',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'len',
      'age' => '13',
      'gender' => 'female',
    ),
  )
```

You could swap the for loop for a foreach:

```
foreach ($names as $k => $v) {
    $out[] = [
        'name'   => $names[$k],
        'age'    => $ages[$k],
        'gender' => $genders[$k]
    ];
}
```